# Searching within cursors?

Tags: android

In android cursors I want to search within that cursor . i already have my query result in a cursor "c" and want to further search on the same cursor "c" with a like query .Any help would be appreciated

I have 2 cursors say

```
c1=fetchalldata();
c2=fetchwithcriteria(criteria);
```

c2 returns a coloumn id ID say at position say P2
I basically want the position of ID in cursor C1 without changing the order of records in c1.

Comment: Why not use get methods on Cursor? I don't think you can execute any query on Cursor results.

Comment: So, you want to get the position of ID from Cursor C1 that is returned from Cursor C2, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved Had to use a loop!!

```
int getPosition(int id){

        c.moveToLast();
        for(int i=c.getCount();i>0;i--,c.moveToPrevious())
            {
                if(id==c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Databaseadapter.KEY_ROWID)))
                {

                     return c.getPosition();
                }
            }

        return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your exact problem or query that you want to perform? Instead of going for searching inside a cursor, you should try to write the query that combines your exact query in one cursor itself. So, better would be write a single query with `INNER JOIN` or fetching Data from `Multiple Tables` or whatever is your query requirement. `Cursor` itself is an result/output of a query, so it won't be possible to write a query on a result.

Comment: I amd displaying some fields using a cursor.now when i want to perform a search i need to use a new cursor with a different like query.as aresult my cursor positon dont matchup in both cursors.and iwant to resume displaying data from my previous cursor pointing at the search reult location.

Comment: It would be better that you re-write/edit your question given complete explanation of what you want to fetch from Table and what search you want to perform after fetching data.

Comment: So, you can use inner join by something like [this example](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/l/aajoins2.htm)